# Python visualization in Power BI with slicers

Tags: python, powerbi

I am trying to create a Python visualization in Power BI from the data in my df and the plot pizza comparison code from mplsoccer: https://mplsoccer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/pizza_plots/plot_pizza_comparison.html

This is my df:

[image: df]

It has a total of 14 columns, the first 2 being the names of the players I want to compare in the visualization. I thought that making 2 columns with the same players maybe would be beneficial when working with slicers (one for Player 1 and one for Player 2) but I don't know if this is correct? If there is a way not to do it, I would appreciate some advice.

The next step I do is to create the Python object with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from highlight_text import fig_text
from mplsoccer import PyPizza, FontManager

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from highlight_text import fig_text

df = dataset
df = df.fillna(0)

params = list(df.columns)
params = params[2:]

jugador1 = df['Jugador 1'].reset_index()
#we pass player's 1 Values : 
jugador1 = list(jugador1.loc[0])

jugador2 = df['Jugador 2'].reset_index()
#we pass player's 2 Values : 
jugador2 = list(jugador2.loc[0])

#we slice the list to remove the index-index-name columns : 
jugador1 = jugador1[3:]
jugador2 = jugador2[3:]

#calculate percentile score of the values compared to the original dataframe :
values1 = []
values2 = []
for x in range(len(params)):
    values1.append(math.floor(stats.percentileofscore(df[params[x]],jugador1[x])))
    
for x in range(len(params)):
    values2.append(math.floor(stats.percentileofscore(df[params[x]],jugador2[x])))


font_normal = FontManager('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/fonts/main/apache/roboto/'
                          'Roboto%5Bwdth,wght%5D.ttf')
font_italic = FontManager('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/fonts/main/apache/roboto/'
                          'Roboto-Italic%5Bwdth,wght%5D.ttf')
font_bold = FontManager('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/fonts/main/apache/robotoslab/'
                        'RobotoSlab%5Bwght%5D.ttf')

# instantiate PyPizza class
baker = PyPizza(
    params=params,                  # list of parameters
    background_color="#EBEBE9",     # background color
    straight_line_color="#222222",  # color for straight lines
    straight_line_lw=1,             # linewidth for straight lines
    last_circle_lw=1,               # linewidth of last circle
    last_circle_color="#222222",    # color of last circle
    other_circle_ls="-.",           # linestyle for other circles
    other_circle_lw=1               # linewidth for other circles
)

# plot pizza
fig, ax = baker.make_pizza(
    values1,                     # list of values
    compare_values=values2,    # comparison values
    figsize=(13,13),             # adjust figsize according to your need
    kwargs_slices=dict(
        facecolor="#1A78CF", edgecolor="#222222",
        zorder=2, linewidth=1
    ),                          # values to be used when plotting slices
    kwargs_compare=dict(
        facecolor="#FF9300", edgecolor="#222222",
        zorder=2, linewidth=1,
    ),
    kwargs_params=dict(
        color="#000000", fontsize=12,
        fontproperties=font_normal.prop, va="center"
    ),                          # values to be used when adding parameter
    kwargs_values=dict(
        color="#000000", fontsize=12,
        fontproperties=font_normal.prop, zorder=3,
        bbox=dict(
            edgecolor="#000000", facecolor="cornflowerblue",
            boxstyle="round,pad=0.2", lw=1
        )
    ),                          # values to be used when adding parameter-values labels
    kwargs_compare_values=dict(
        color="#000000", fontsize=12, fontproperties=font_normal.prop, zorder=3,
        bbox=dict(edgecolor="#000000", facecolor="#FF9300", boxstyle="round,pad=0.2", lw=1)
    ),                          # values to be used when adding parameter-values labels
)

# add title
fig_text(
    0.515, 0.99, "Comparison between Player 1 and Player 2", size=17, fig=fig,
    highlight_textprops=[{"color": '#1A78CF'}, {"color": '#EE8900'}],
    ha="center", fontproperties=font_bold.prop, color="#000000"
)

plt.show()
```

I also create 2 independent slicers for Player 1 and another one for Player 2. That is, when choosing an option in Player 1, the slicer of Player 2 is not filtered and so I can choose another different player to compare their metrics. This is how is shown:

[image: powerbi]

But as you can see, there is an error:

[image: error]

I think the key is in these lines of code:

```
jugador1 = df['Jugador 1'].reset_index()
#we pass player's 1 Values : 
jugador1 = list(jugador1.loc[0])

jugador2 = df['Jugador 2'].reset_index()
#we pass player's 2 Values : 
jugador2 = list(jugador2.loc[0])

#we slice the list to remove the index-index-name columns : 
jugador1 = jugador1[3:]
jugador2 = jugador2[3:]
```

However, I don't know exactly what might be going wrong. I also tried removing `.reset_index()` but it didn't work. It's something related to lists, ranges and index but I don't have the knowledge to find it.

How can I solve it? I need exactly that radar chart and I'm very interested in working with slicers in Power BI + Python. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

`df['Jugador 1']` only selects the name column of your dataframe.
So you will not be able to select any player values from this column.

To get the values for a player, you want to select a full row from you dataset, not just a single column.
To do that, you can just use a single "Jugador"-column and filter the dataframe based on that column.

Here's a minimal example on how to get the values with that method:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
        "Jugador": ["Louis", "Antonio"],
        "Non-Penalty Goals": [10, 8],
        "npxG": [12.5, 9.3],
        "npxG per Shot": [0.15, 0.12],
})

params = df.columns[1:]

# select players
player_1 = "Louis"
player_2 = "Antonio"

# get player values by filtering the full dataframe via Jugador column
player_1_values = df[df["Jugador"]==player_1].iloc[0].values[1:]
player_2_values = df[df["Jugador"]==player_2].iloc[0].values[1:]
```

Comment: I know what you mean but it doesn't solve my issue because it's not a problem of the Python code but of Power BI and how to interact with the slicers. I know that if, for instance, I specify a specific player I can do his graph (like you said ´==player_1´). My problem comes because I want to create 2 filters in Power BI where I can choose from a list both players and automatically show the visualization, not having to write in the Python code the specific players. For this I need to know where my code is failing when integrating it with Power BI. I hope I have explained myself better

Comment: how can it not be a problem of the python code? you have a python exception, you have a clear root cause (accessing the name column only), and with a code modification you should get rid of the error...? I am not a Power BI user, so I cannot follow your workflow, but from what you are describing, I still see the wrong python code as the cause of the issue.  Can you maybe upload a pbix file to fully reproduce the problem in power BI?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's a Python code, you are right and your code works for comparing Louis and Antonio. But I need something interactive in Power BI, where the user can choose in 2 slicers between Louis, Antonio or different player and then get the plot comparing both players. The pbix can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z7CFRx6BPwiAVkcp9i_eIPts38zCOyfa/view?usp=sharing Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I tried to come up with a solution for power BI, but those slicers will not let me access the original data. One can use a single single with multi-select (Ctrl-Click) to get to rows, but then one is not able to get the relative percentiles with regargs to all other players, because all other players are filtered out already. Maybe it will work when you already calculate the relative data in the original data frame and then use multi select to get two row from a single "Jugador" column, and access the precalculated relative data from here, but I give up :)